# Is there a notation for $((n!)!)!$?

Tags: notation, terminology

I wonder if there is a notation for repeating factorials such as $((3!)!)!$.

Without the parentheses, $(3!)!$ could be confused with the double factorial $3!!$.

Is there is no such notation known, I would suggest the following analogue to Knuth's
up arrow notation:

a!1 := a!

a!(n+1) := (a!n)!

for all n>=1

So, for example

3!4=(((3!)!)!)!

Comment: I won't edit the second part because I don't know how to express what you are trying to say. Are you okay with $3!^{(4)}=(((3!)!)!)!$? If yes, I'll edit it.

Comment: @Ian this could be confused with ${3!}^{4}$

Comment: I know you set parantheses ...

Comment: Ok, but it is considerably better than $3!4$. Perhaps it could be $3!_{(4)}$, then?

Comment: I propose $3(!)^4$. :-)

Comment: @IanMateus I'd like to point out that the notation $n!^{(k)}$ is already used for general multifactorials (double, triple, etc....).  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Multifactorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\gamma(n)=n!$, then $\gamma^k(n)=(((\ldots n!)!)\ldots )$. So we could use the Gamma function shifted by $1$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any well-known notation for iterated factorials. They don't seem to be a very common concept -- googling "iterated factorial" doesn't seem to find anything except warning that this is *not* what the double factorial means, and programming talk about computing factorials using iteration.

Of course, if you're writing something where you need to speak about both double factorials and iterated factorials, you're free to define a notation for it yourself, such as the one you suggest here. Just don't expect it to make it into textbooks unless you show that iterated factorials can be used for something *really* amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. There is a notation alrady. As you already write, it is:

$$((n!)!)!$$

(The question is, why it matters? It won't harm if you invent one notation.)

Comment: If there are 100 "!", it would be awful to write it out.